# WordPress/WooCommerce stock not working correct

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I entered my stock manually, as I have an old-fashioned cash register at the company.
However, I have now products that I had removed, put drafts, adjusted price, suddenly reappearing. Sometimes also products that have been removed from the collection for a long time ago.
The person who manages my webshop doesn't understand it and says this can be done by a 3rd party such as *Sendcloud*, but this is not possible, right? I've been working with them for years and never had a problem. Does anyone know of this problem, or is there a plugin that can cause this?

We tried to uninstall plugins we don't use, tried to read the error log (but I don't find any), tried to log the activity by a plugin (but nothing was suspicious).

Comment: Seriously, nobody is going to be able guessing what is going wrong on your e-shop by magic… You need to find out someone enough skilled that can make a complete audit and watch out during a certain period of time.

Comment: It's a great awnser thanks, I do have a lot of skills. But everytime the stock getting somehow automatic reseted and there is no logic explination yet why so. And yeah we would love too know the magic or a way to figure out where we can get more info about the magic haha. And thanks for the downvote also realy helpfull

Answer (score 0):

The problem was indeed in Sendcloud after we have removed this plugin it didn't effect the database anymore. Kind of a bad service if you are controlling the stock by the Dashboard of Woocommerce and not trough SendCloud. Thank you for the help.